# wxclips: [MSGFUN1] and [MSGPASS2] while trying to use instances

Tags: clips

I'm trying to run classes in wxclips  but its not working anyidea what's wrong.
Note this code is from tutorials and it should be working but it isn't

```
   > CLIPS> (defclass A (is-a USER)   (role concrete)  (slot foo (create-accessor write))   (slot bar)) 
   > CLIPS> (make-instance a of A (foo 36)) [a] CLIPS> (make-instance b of A (bar 45)) [MSGFUN1]
   > No applicable primary message-handlers found for put-bar. FALSE CLIPS>

> CLIPS>(defclass person (is-a USER) (multislot full-name) (role concrete) (slot gender (allowed-symbols male female)) (slot age))
> CLIPS>(definstances people (mike of person(gender "male")(age 24))) 
> CLIPS>(send [mike] get-gender)
[MSGPASS2] No such instance mike in function send
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create slot accessors for any slot you want to read or write and instances from definstances are not created until you issue a (reset) command.

```
CLIPS> (defclass A (is-a USER) (role concrete) (slot foo(create-accessor write)) (slot bar (create-accessor write))) 
CLIPS> (make-instance a of A (foo 36)) 
[a]
CLIPS> (make-instance b of A (bar 45)) 
[b]
CLIPS> (defclass person (is-a USER) (multislot full-name) (role concrete) (slot gender (allowed-symbols male female) (create-accessor read-write)) (slot age (create-accessor read-write)))
CLIPS> (definstances people (mike of person(gender "male")(age 24))) 
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (send [mike] get-gender)
"male"
```